# how to run an exe from a unc path with parameters in ruby

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to run a executable from my ruby script, and pass in some parameters to it at the same time.
currently i have:

```
command = Thread.new do 
  return_code = system('\\\\file-server\\share1\\data_app.exe -gTest -d20120914')
end
command.join
```

But this doesn't work.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? What does it say? Does the app get executed in the thread? Does the system command work without the thread? etc.

Comment: Does File.exists?('\\\\file-server\\share1\\data_app.exe')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure it out. It was related to how my application functions and looks for it's dependancies. I needed to set the working directory before calling the application, which you can do with:

```
Dir.chdir('\\\\file-server\\share1\\')
```

Thanks for your help!